# Access to the path 'xxx' is denied (where 'xxx' is a folder)

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-7.5

I know this has been asked before many times, but I have browsed tens of similar questions without help.

This error is showed when my asp.net 4.0 application tries to access a folder on my local drive, doing this:

```
XmlTextReader confReader = new XmlTextReader (filename);           
while (confReader.Read())  // <- error line
{
  // do something
}
```

In my web.config I have <Identity Impersonate="true">. For the folder I have assigned full-access to:

```
everyone 
IIS APPPOOL\<custom apppoolname> 
NETWORK SERVICE
```

Debugging the application, I can put up a watch which evaluates this call right before the incriminated line:

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.ToString();
```

the call shows the current user is IIS APPPOOL\<custom apppoolname>.

I'm on Windows 7 64bit with Sp1. I know it's probably something stupid but I have already spent an awful amount of time on this.

**Edit**:
The problem was in the variable "filename", which pointed to the right folder, but for a configuration problem the filename was missing (i.e. the content was "c:\data\" instead of "c:\data\file.xml"). The Asp.net error was actually confusing, since I had all the right permissions to access that folder. DJKRAZE pointed me to the right direction.

Comment: where are you declaring filename..? does the file even exist..? do you have rights to that folder..? have you tried running VS as Admin..? do you have Virtual Directory setup for the web app..sounds like you have a few things configured improperly as well but can't really tell based on the code for starters this line `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.ToString();` should yield your `domain\\username or compuername\\username`

Comment: give us the debugging info from the stack trace. for us to help you, we need details f.cipriani!

Comment: If IIS Doesn't have permission to the directory, then it will throw an exception.  It's usually better to use a Network Local account so it does the request based on the local machine. Not impersonate.

Comment: Also is it a UNC, a local path, etc? Make sure Windows and that NTFS Account has NTFS permissions to that directory, share, path, etc.

Comment: @DJKRAZE thanks, that was it, the problem was "filename" had a valid path to the folder "xxx", but there wasn't a file name appended (wrong configuration, my fault). Actually I was confused by the error message. If you can make it an answer I'll be glad to accept it.

Comment: `+1` @f.cipriani I have posted my comment as an answer. Glad that it was a simple fix / solution that I was able to quickly notice

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: FYI, you should not use `new XmlTextReader()` or `new XmlTextWriter()`. They have been deprecated since .NET 2.0. Use `XmlReader.Create()` or `XmlWriter.Create()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I would suggest checking

`where are you declaring filename..?`
 `Does the file even exist..?`

do you have rights to that folder..? have you tried running VS as Admin..? do you have Virtual Directory setup for the web app..sounds like you have a few things configured improperly as well but can't really tell based on the code for starters this line `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.ToString();`
 should yield your `domain\\username or compuername\\username`

Glad that `FileName` was all it was

Answer (score 0):

IIS requires the path to a folder in the server machine has rights for `Anonymous` user login to access.

Make sure the user `Anonymous` has the rights to access the folder.